# sqldf gives error while using subquery

Tags: mysql, r, sqldf

I'm trying to get moving average by weekday, for that I'm using sql query.
Dataframe is

[image: data]

and sqldf code:

```
ma_782 =  sqldf("SELECT  
         t1.Id_indicator,   t1.Hour,  
 (  
  select SUM(t2.Value) / COUNT(t2.Value)                                 
    FROM  max_value_782 AS t2  
    WHERE   
        t1.Hour = t2.Hour and  
             weekdays.Date(t1.Date) = weekdays.Date(t2.Date)  
            and DATEDIFF(t1.Date, t2.Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 42        
  ) AS 'MA_by_weekday'  
FROM max_value_782 AS t1  ;")
```

This gives error

> Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error

while it works from simple select:

```
sqldf("select * from max_value_782")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider replacing the `weekdays.` method as this syntax assumes a table qualifier. Since by default sqldf uses the SQLite dialect, use `strftime` to compare weekdays.  Also, single quotes are used for string literals and not to enclose table/field identifiers. SQLite can uses brackets, backticks, or double quotes, or none if reserved words/special characters are not used.

```
ma_782 =  sqldf("SELECT  t1.Id_indicator, t1.Hour,  
                         (SELECT AVG(t2.Value)
                          FROM max_value_782 AS t2  
                          WHERE t1.Hour = t2.Hour 
                          AND strftime('%w', t1.Date) = strftime('%w', t2.Date)  
                          AND (t2.Date - t2.Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 42        
                         ) AS MA_by_weekday  
                FROM max_value_782 AS t1;")
```

Comment: Note that the semicolon is not needed.

Comment: No problem...Glad to help. Happy coding!